# Can std::set::insert() call the assignment operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a class with custom assignment operator that deliberately introduces controlled side effects.

If I have a `std::set` of these elements, I would like to know whether the assignment operator could be called with the use of `insert`.

I.e.:

```
class A
{
public:
    A & operator=(A const & rhs)
    {
        // custom assignment operator with deliberate side effects
        // Could this be called with use of std::set::insert()?
    }
};

std::set<A> a;

// Is it possible with this, or any use of "insert", that
// the assignment operator will ever be called?

a.insert(A());
```

Can the assignment operator ever be called with the use of `std::set::insert`?

Comment: what side effects? can you debug the code ? , best way to find out is to put a breakpoint inside `operator =`

Comment: @Dan Nissenbaum after a small test it appears the `operator =` is **not** called.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That will tell him whether his current implementation uses the assignment operator in the particular case that he tests.  It won't tell him if it is guaranteed not to.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes - I have already tested that in my code, the assignment operator is not called.  However, this code is cross-platform and will be built on Clang and possibly other platforms.  Also, I do not have confidence that there are not edge cases that I have not tested for.  I'd like to know if there is a guarantee in the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++11 standard requires types to be used with `std::set::insert` to be "CopyInsertable
", "MoveInsertable" or "EmplaceConstructible" depending on the insert function you are using (23.2.3/4).

This is for example defined as:

> T is EmplaceConstructible into X from args, for zero or more arguments args, means that the following expression is well-formed: `allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, args);` (23.2.1/13)

In all three cases, the default behaviour is `std::allocator` which uses placement new (17.6.3.5/2):

```
::new((void*)c)A(forward<Args>(args)...)
```

Depending on the `insert` function, in our case `args` is either an expression of type `A`, an rvalue of type `A` or some other arguments. But in all cases a constructor or copy constructor is used, not the assignment operator.

This is what the standard says (and GCC 4.6.3 does). Even if there is no reason to use the assignment operator, some compiler may still do it. So I would suggest don't rely too much on it.

Answer (score 3):

In pre-C++11, it could, theoretically.  C++11 bans it, no doubt
because no implementation ever actually did it.  In C++11,
members of `std::set` don't have to support assignment.
In pre-C++11, some implementations supporting concepts might
have code which uses assignment, as a means of checking that
your class supports it, but it should be in a non-evaluated
context, so the operator will not actually be called.

Comment: Elements of `set` may not have to support assignment, but does the Standard ban using it if present ? One could expect an implementation to have two code-paths: one optimized for assignment and the other "typical", and pick one or the other at compile-time using type-traits.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That's a good question.  I don't think the standard addresses it directly, but... since it doesn't put any constraints on an assignment operator, an implementation could not count on it doing what was expected, and so could not use it.  (In practice, as I said, no implementation actually used it, which is why the standard no longer requires it.)

Comment: @MatthieuM. and James Kanze - I have found that in Release mode, the optimizer in Visual Studio 2013 utilizes the assignment operator, rather than the constructor, for bulk `insert`.  When I build and run the identical code in Debug mode, the assignment operator is never called.  However, in Release mode, the identical code calls the assignment operator.  This was revealed to me because my side effects were triggered upon `insert`, but only in Release mode (and I confirmed it explicitly with a `throw` in the assignment operator, which is only triggered in Release mode).

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: Now *that* is unexpected, I would not have expected a difference in the *front-end* depending on Debug vs Release.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I appreciate the optimizing compiler - in my case, with a massive number (10's of millions) of inserts via bulk (range-based) `insert`, the Release-mode build is running almost 100x faster than the Debug-mode build (15 seconds vs. 20 minutes), so I am pleased the optimizer is pulling out all the stops.  It seems the optimizer is re-using previously allocated blocks of objects, and just assigning to them during the bulk `insert`.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: I understand you would appreciate it :) It is just than I would have expected the C++ -> IR translation to be always the same (as they are in Clang to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: @MatthieuM. I made a mistake.  My copy constructor was calling my assignment operator.  Still, the fact that `insert` was calling the copy constructor in Release mode is still worthy of similar comments, I think.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Insert must call the copy constructor at some point.  As for differences between between optimization and normal compilation, they shouldn't impact observable behavior _unless_ the copy constructor doesn't really copy (or has observable side effects) _or_ the code has undefined behavior.